# Typescript oneOf Type for classes

Tags: typescript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, typescript-typings

```
class CoreClass {
    coreProp: string
    // cannot do classABProp: string | number
    // as it interferes with persistence and cannot be easily 
    // used to define database schema. 
}

class ClassA extends CoreClass {
    classAProp: string

};

class ClassB extends CoreClass {
    classBPorp: number
};

class SubClass extends CoreClass {
    // Expected Props    
    // coreProp: string
    // classAProp: string || classBPorp: number
    // should have atleast one of the two.

}
```

So i was looking for a neat way of doing this.
I am not reluctant to define SubClass twice which is essentially doing the same thing.

I do have a constructor for each class so i am really not looking to define separate types for accomplishing the same.

Seems like a trivial problem but i am unable to get my head around it.

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me what `Subclass` is supposed to be... If you want a type representing any subclass you could use a union type `type Subclass = ClassA  | ClassB`

Comment: Well SubClass will have a constructor of its own,  so assigning it as a type is not the best way of doing it.

Comment: So `Subclass` need to inherit from both `ClassA` and `ClassB` ? Or you just want to make sure it implements the same interface as `ClassA` and `Class B`

Comment: `SubClass` should have all the properties of `CoreClass` and should have `classAProp` or `classBProp` but should have at least one of the two prop. That is what i meant by oneOf type, for types on could easily do it with a union operator, not very how to do the same with classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking to define interfaces instead of classes here. How about:

```
interface CommonInterface {
  coreProp: string
}

interface InterfaceA extends CommonInterface {
    classAProp: string
};

interface InterfaceB extends CommonInterface {
    classBProp: number
};

type CoreInterface = InterfaceA | InterfaceB;

const testStringProp: CoreInterface = { coreProp: 'test', classAProp: "testString" };
const testNumberProp: CoreInterface = { coreProp: 'test', classBProp: 43 };

const testError: CoreInterface = { coreProp: 'test' }; 
//error: needs either classAProp or classBProp
```

Implementing the interfaces by instantiating new objects:

```
class CommonClass {
    coreProp: string
    // ...
}

class ClassA extends CommonClass {
    classAProp: string;

    constructor(props: InterfaceA) {
        super();
        this.coreProp = props.coreProp;
        this.classAProp = props.classAProp;
    }
};

class ClassB extends CommonClass {
    classBProp: number;

    constructor(props: InterfaceB) {
        super();
        this.coreProp = props.coreProp;
        this.classBProp = props.classBProp;
    }
};

class ClassAorB extends CommonClass {
    classAProp: string;
    classBProp: number;

    constructor(props: CoreInterface) {
        super();
        this.coreProp = props.coreProp;
        const propsA = props as InterfaceA;
        const propsB = props as InterfaceB;
        if (propsA.classAProp) {
            this.classAProp = propsA.classAProp
        }
        if (propsB.classBProp) {
            this.classBProp = propsB.classBProp
        }
    }
};


const objOfClassA = new ClassA({ coreProp: 'test', classAProp: 'testString' });
const objOfClassB = new ClassB({ coreProp: 'test', classBProp: 43 });
const objA = new ClassAorB({ coreProp: 'test', classAProp: 'testing' });
const objB = new ClassAorB({ coreProp: 'test', classBProp: 43 });

const testError = new ClassB({coreProp: 'test'}); 
//error: needs classBProp
const testAntotherErr = new ClassAorB({coreProp: 'test'}) 
//error: needs either classAProp or classBProp
```

Comment: Well i did mention 'I do have a constructor for each class so i am really not looking to define separate types for accomplishing the same.'. These are dummy classes actual classes have 15 to 20 props it is really not possible to use types in such a scenario one needs to use classes and inheritance.

Comment: Updated to include an example of class instantiation

Comment: So the issue with this approach is if i do `
objA.classBProp` it does not give an error. Even though objA does not have classBProp.